# How to use a single connection to the network in several classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Guys help deal with a problem I'm new to programming, and accordingly I have a problem in general, I do not know how to work with the network! I wrote a class in which I log into the site after login I can not use the connection to send other requests in other views!!!
here's what I wrote:

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[txtUserName text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Пожалуйста заполните все поля!!!" :@"Авторизация не удолась!"];
        } else {

            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[txtUserName text],[txtPassword text]];


            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chgu.org/?mobile=1"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSData *responseData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:urlData];
                NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                if([jsonObject objectForKey:@"error"])
                {
                    [self alertStatus:@"Ошибка ввода данных" :@"Ю хав а трабл"];

                } else {

                    [self alertStatus:@"Авторизация прошла успешно" :@""];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }

    [txtUserName resignFirstResponder];
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
}
```

how do I use this connection when I move to a different view!
Please tell me anything all night sitting at the computer can not figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, assuming that you want relatively tight coupling between these controllers via that delegate protocol.

Since neither controller knows about the other until that delegate property is set you need to have some object which has a reference to both of them wire up that relationship. In your case that's probably the application delegate which can create both controllers, set one as the delegate of the other, and pass both along to your tab bar controller.

What you might actually want is to have the app delegate give both controllers a reference to some shared model object. Your FirstViewController can update that model when you tap a button and your SecondViewController can observe changes to the model to update it's display (or just update its view when it appears based on the current model state). That way your controllers don't need to know anything about each other.

**in secondVC, define something like the following:**

```
@protocol secondVCDelegate

@interface secondVC : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id<secondVCDelegate> delegate;
@end


@optional
-(void)someDelegateMethod:(secondVC*)viewController;

@end
```

**at the time of creating the instance of secondVC you must assign the delegate property of secondVC to self! something like this:**

```
// in firstVC
secondVC vc = [[secondVC alloc]...];
vc.delegate = self;
[navcontroller pushVC:vc];
the line vc.delegate = self; does the trick.
```

hope it helps...